# php and rails on same server linux hosting

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, hosting

I am new to hosting services

i have a domain for ex www.example.com which is running in php
so in public_html i have put all php files

i have multi hosting support(which support ruby on rails ,php etc)

so i want to create a sub domain in ruby on rails

for ex: sub.ecample.com which should point to public_html/sub

i tried rails new sub from ssh(putty) it created application folders etc inside sub 
but when we got to link sub.ecample.com or ecample.com/sub   its just showing directory list

Please help
i am not sure if any configurations etc is needed to run rails

*If this post is  marked as duplicate  or any deleted etc please provide helping links as comments
i didnt find any helping links/questions etc

Comment: I feel like this is more a question for your Web host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, the fix for this will be to talk with your web host specifically.

However, to give you a clearer picture of what to do, you have several important options:

---

**Server Software**

The first, and most important, step is to ensure you have the right server software installed, or at least have it pointing to your sub domain correctly

I'm not sure how a *shared* hosting provider will handle this, but the typical way for a VPS / "self hosted" system to be set up is to use one of the popular open source server applications; typically Apache or Nginx.

If you use either of these (as I am sure is the same with the other server variants out there), the setup permits you the provision for "virtual hosts". These give you the ability to host multiple websites on a single server

Without going into too much detail (you'll be best enquiring with your host about it), you'll want to look at these resources:

> - [Deploying to a VPS (Railscasts)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps?view=comments)
> - [DigitalOcean deployment guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-unicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-6-5)
> - [GoRails deployment guide](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04)

All of these will advise you to install one of the open source server applications, which will give you the ability to then route the different subdomains / requests to the respective applications you have.

---

**Public**

Secondly, you have to consider the importance of routing to your Rails application correctly.

Rails applications are not like PHP - they are *real applications*, meaning they run on your localized system, accepting input from the HTTP protocol. That's how you can go into the "Rails Console" - because the application runs on your local ruby installation, taking any requests from the "server", which Rails can then process.

The problem you have is that if you're just routing to the Rails "root" directory, which won't load the files correctly. If you want the application to load as required, you have to point your web server to the `/public` directory.

I'm not sure *how* Rails manages this, but every time you send a request to the application, it will observe the `public` directory, which will then send the request through to your Rails backend. In short, you need to route to your `/public` folder:

```
#etc/nginx/nginx.conf
server { 
  listen 80; 
  server_name example.com; 
  passenger_enabled on; 
  root /var/www/my_awesome_rails_app/public; 
}
```

Comment: @Rixh Peck What is passenger? is it useful for this?

Comment: Passenger is the Rails' preferred hosting system. I'm not sure how it works exactly - I just know it's truly amazing! You can see it by looking up Phusion Passenger - you'll have to ensure you set it up with your webhost first